# Rename multiple files - linux/ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, directory, rename

I need to remove the "_1331045422" from image files in my directory.

for eg., my image file name looks like: **message-16-error_1331045422.png**

I actually ran a script which rename all image files this way.
Also I have other files (image files with correct names, js files and css etc. which have correct names)

Please help me with a command to rename all image files with the "_1331045422" , without affecting others.

EDIT:
I not only have .png files with the wrong filename. There are gifs and jpegs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rename command:

`rename 's/_\d+(\..{1,3})/$1/g' *`

You can change the range between {} if you have files with extension longer than three chars.

Be carefull that on some system the rename command is a bit different.
Have a look here:
https://superuser.com/questions/70217/is-there-a-linux-command-like-mv-but-with-regex

Comment: super cool. It would be great if this worked for files inside sub-directories too

Comment: No recursive option for rename. You need a bash script to go further. But I agree, rename it's great. It's a pity that on some system, like slackware, there's the "wrong" version.

Comment: How do I delete files with such filenames?

Comment: @AravindVel `find -regex '.*_[0-9]+\.png' -delete`

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your files before trying this!!

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.png; 
    do mv $i `echo $i | sed  "s/_[0-9]\+\.png^/\.png/"`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# message-16-error_1331045422.png --> message-16-error.png
# Usage: python foo.py dir_to_change
import os, sys
dir=sys.argv[1]
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if not file.endswith('.png'):
        continue
    new, end = file.rsplit('_', 1)
    new=u'%s.png' % new
    file_old=os.path.join(dir, file)
    file_new=os.path.join(dir, new)
    os.rename(file_old, file_new)
```

Comment: I have added an info at the end of my question. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

With [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm):

```
rnm -rs '/_\d+(\.)(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)/\1\2/' *
```

More examples [here](https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm/).